# How to download a python package using pip into google Cloud Storage bucket with public access and to install from there

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, pip, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to download python package using pip into Google Cloud Storage bucket with the following command `pip3 download pandas --download="gs://public_bucket/"` but I am getting the following error on using it: `no such option: --download`.

I would also like to know how I can install from bucket directly using pip.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you ultimately trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think your goal cannot be performed using only pip3 since there's no integration between GCS and pip, I've looked for the [options of pip command](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/python3-pip/pip3.1.en.html) and I could find the --download option, which allows you to point a directory to download the desired package.

Since there's no integration between the Cloud Storage API and pip, I think you might copy the downloaded packages by using [gsutil cp](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) command. And perform the installation with the same strategy.